# How to check href of an element found using xpath contains text()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to find an element by the text it contains, then check that that element also has a link to a particular place. I'm using selenium/java.

I'm trying to find elements by text when I can to minimise how many changes I will need to make if the UI is updated (reduce test maintenance costs).

I've tried the following, but the assert fails as the getAttribute ends up being null.

```java
WebElement newsHeadlineTemplate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'News Headline')]"));
Assert.assertEquals("Template not clickable", "/news/create/new", newsHeadlineTemplate.getAttribute("href"));
```

HTML for element I'm trying to find/use:

```html
<div class="columns">
   <div class="column is-one-third">
      <p>News Headline</p>
      <a href="/news/create/new"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm still fairly new to selenium so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath selector is a little bit wrong, you're matching [`<p>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) and you need to match the [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) which is the [following-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) for the `<p>` tag.

So you need to amend your expression to look like:

```
//p[text()='News Headline']/following-sibling::a
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)